# Using XML::LibXML: How do I create namespaces and child elements and make them work together?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-namespaces, libxml2

I'm trying to do some stuff with FOAF and Perl. I'm unhappy with the current solutions and I want to roll my own. Please do not reference any module other than `XML::LibXML`.

For reference here is a snippet from a FOAF file

```
<rdf:RDF
      xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
      xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
      xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
      xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">

  <foaf:Person rdf:ID="me">
  <foaf:name>Evan Carroll</foaf:name>
....
```

Now, excluding whitespace, I'm trying to recreate this with `XML::LibXML`. However, I'm unfortunately stuck on the very first line. This just focuses on the first line:

I read this to be

1. element `RDF`, in namespace `rdf` declares

   1. attribute `rdf` in namespace `xmlns` with value `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#`
   2. attribute `rdfs` in namespace `xmlns` with value `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#`
   3. attribute `foaf` in namespace `xmlns` with value `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`
   4. attribute `admin` in namespace `xmlns` with value `http://webns.net/mvcb/`

Firstly you need an element `rdf:RDF`, this seems to be tricky. Reading the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod) for `XML::LibXML::Document` I found `createElementNS()` but this doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
my $foaf = $doc->createElementNS( 'RDF', 'rdf' );
print $foaf->toString; # prints <rdf xmlns="RDF"/>
```

Now, I try `createElement('rdf:RDF')` and it works! I got the root element `rdf:RDF`. Is this how we're supposed to create root elements? Am I just reading XML wrong?

Now, I need to create the attributes (schema declarations). I tried the poorly documented `XML::LibXML::Document`'s `createAttributeNS` but it didn't work either:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
my $foaf = $doc->createElement( 'rdf:RDF' );
$doc->createAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'rdf' );
```

In fact I get this error: *"can't create a new namespace on an attribute!"* which seems contradictory to what the method name implies, and to its description on the docs: *"Creates an Attribute bound to a namespace."*

So, I figure, ok I can't `create` an `attributeNS`, maybe I can `set` an `attributeNS` then. And, I proceed with the next documented method this time on `XML::LibXML::Element` that looks applicable: `setAttributeNS`.

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
my $foaf = $doc->createElement( 'rdf:RDF' );
$foaf->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'rdf' );
```

This time I get a different error: *"bad ns attribute!"*. So I review some of the tests, and find this one requires a attribute key-value other than the namespace declaration to do what I want.. Which isn't what I want.

Here are some possible combinations and outputs:

```
$foaf->setAttributeNS( http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'rdf:', undef );
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:=""/>

$foaf->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'rdf:foo', 'bar' );
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:foo="bar"/>
```

It seems none of the *NS methods work, even though I know they are related to XML namespaces. Finally, I try the non-NS version:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
my $foaf = $doc->createElement( 'rdf:RDF' );
$foaf->setAttribute( 'xmlns:rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' );
print $foaf->toString; # <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
```

I get this horrible feeling that I'm **not doing this right**. Did I do this right? How do I add a child Element with the DOM (not using `appendTextChild`)?

This whole `XML::LibXML` is *very* poorly documented but seems to be the best Perl has to offer for fast XML creation with a DOM.

Comment: Since Evan has explicitly prohibited it I won't mention any other modules, but I will note that when working with RDF, an RDF-specific module would be better, especially since XML is a poor serialization of RDF.

Comment: I'm doing this for FOAF, if you know of a more widespread adoption of it than XML then go for it! If not, what I'm trying to do is create a model that will give you FOAF and HCARD templates and renderings from within TT and Catalyst. More specifically to create social-web type stuff and cater to crawlers that can utilize it (google maps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**From memory** (and edited for correctness), you do it like this:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
my $foaf = $doc->createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'RDF' );
$doc->setDocumentElement( $foaf );
$foaf->setNamespace( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' , 'rdf', 1 );
$foaf->setNamespace( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#' , 'rdfs', 0 );
$foaf->setNamespace( 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/' , 'foaf', 0 );
$foaf->setNamespace( 'http://webns.net/mvcb/' , 'admin', 0 );
my $node = $doc->createElementNS( 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/', 'Person');
$foaf->appendChild($node);
$node->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'ID', 'me');
my $node2 = $doc->createElementNS( 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/', 'name');
$node2->appendTextNode('Evan Carroll');
$node->appendChild($node2);
print $doc->toString;
```

That is, you always need to use the namespace URIs and add the namespace declarations to your root node (this is the only place you specify the namespace prefix - I think libxml will invent its own prefixes if you don't provide them). It would obviously be sensible from the maintenance point of view to put these in some variables.

Your final (non-namespaced) version will work as long as you don't need the in-memory DOM to be namespace aware. This works as the Level 1 DOM does not know about namespaces: you can treat namespaces as ordinary attributes and the document will still be well formed (but possibly not namespace well formed).

This works to a point, but the namespace prefixes are not as given. A discussion of this [is elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359920/using-perls-xmllibxml-how-do-you-use-xml-prefixes-and-not-xmlns-attributes).

Comment: This is a great post but it doesn't compile at all for me? Any ideas?

Comment: @Evan: what part doesn't compile?

Comment: Fails to compile with XML::LibXML 1.70: Can't locate object method "createElementNS" via package "XML::LibXML::Element"

Comment: It's been said that the W3C DOM API is rather counter intuitive. Try this version.

Comment: `createElementNS` is a method of the document.  I think you want `addNewChild` when creating child nodes.  Also, isn't `name` supposed to be a child of `Person`, not the root node?

Comment: Ok - I think that the an error appending the attribute. Is this any better?

Comment: That seems to work pretty much (forgot a few semicolons) it has `<Person xmlns="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" rdf:ID="me"><name>Evan Carroll</name></Person>`, my first question would be how do you make a node that consists of `<foaf:Person rdf:ID="me">`. I know how to setAttributeNS but how do you create NS-aware a `<foaf:Person>` node?

Comment: I think this question is answered here: http://www.justskins.com/forums/namespace-declarations-in-libxml-101052-2.html It appears as if they're syntactically the same, and XML::LibXML doesn't support the pretty NS option. I wonder if social-crawling mechanism in google will pick up `<person xmlns="foafurl">` or not...

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, see my follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359920/using-perls-xmllibxml-how-do-you-use-xml-prefixes-and-not-xmlns-attributes